# What does the `i` do in Chrome's user agent stylesheet for checkboxes/radios?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I noticed something strange in Google Chrome's user agent stylesheet. What does the `i` mean/do in these selectors (after `type=""`)?

```
input[type="radio" i],
input[type="checkbox" i] {
  background-color: initial;
  margin: 3px 0.5ex;
  padding: initial;
  border: initial;
}
```

Comment: Ok this is a duplicate, but no way you can find this on Google searching for a single character..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes the preceding attribute selector case-insensitive, so it matches `<input type="RaDiO">` as well:

```
[attr operator value i]
```

> Adding an i (or I) before the closing bracket causes the value to be
>   compared case-insensitively (for characters within the ASCII range).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Eagle eye :D. I couldn't find this :/.

Comment: If anyone sees this and wants to use it in production, [neither IE or Edge support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-case-insensitive) :( There's probably a polyfill out there though....

Comment: Awesome thanks! There was no way of finding this, trying to search for a single character in an expression :P